# No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of ‘res’

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.List

s = "123456789"

fibs = 1 : scanl (+) 1 fibs
res (x:xs) = if (sort. show $ div x (10^(floor(m) - 8))) == s then x else res       xs
 where m = logBase 10 x
```

The code picks the first 9 digits of a fib number and checks if they match the variable s. I have tried to fix this by inserting fromIntegral in various areas, but I can't seem to make it work, especially because the of the error references the function 'res'. Please point me in the right direction.

The error I get is:

```
No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of ‘res’
In the expression: res fibs
In an equation for ‘it’: it = res fibs
```

Comment: Please print the compiler error as well.

Comment: Compiler error is:

Comment: No instance for (Floating Integer) arising from a use of ‘res’
        In the expression: res fibs
        In an equation for ‘it’: it = res fibs

Comment: Please in the future [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41828859/edit) your question.

Comment: I'm running the code by typing res fibs in GHCI 7.10.3.  and...noted Willem.

Comment: it appears tha the error is not in the function itself. That one compiles, please show the calling code.

Comment: I call by typing res fibs in GHCI 7.10.3

Comment: Why not just use `sort . take 9 . show $ x` instead? `res = head . filter ((== "123456789") . sort . take 9 . show) $ fibs`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call `res fib` directly because `res` has type:

```
res :: (Floating r, Integral r, RealFrac r, Show r) => [r] -> r
```

it thus requires a type that is `Floating`, `Integral`, `RealFrac` and `Show`.

Now it seems that you simply constructed a function that is very problematic for types: you expect the type to be both `Floating` and `Integral`.

You can however rewrite your function to:

```
res (x:xs) | s == sort (show (div x (10^(m - 8)))) = x
           | otherwise = res xs
           where m = floor $ logBase 10 $ fromIntegral x
```

now `res` has type:

```
res :: (Integral a, Show a) => [a] -> a
```

If I now run `res fib`, it gives:

```
*Main> res fibs
*** Exception: Negative exponent
```

which is logical, because you feed it a negative exponent `(10^(m-8))`. My guess is that you simply want to omit these cases, so that you rewrite it to:

```
res (x:xs) | m >= 8 && s == sort (show (div x (10^(m - 8)))) = x
           | otherwise = res xs
           where m = floor $ logBase 10 $ fromIntegral x
```

If I now run `res fibs` the program seems to calculate (and does not find a solution in reasonable time, it eventually even eats all available memory).

If you want to inspect that every digit is present however, you cannot simply use sort, since sort will not filter out duplicates.

Comment: Many thanks Willem for your detailed explanation. This is very helpful.